# podman ENTRYPOINT/CMD behaviour issues on Azure

Tags: azure, environment, slurm, podman, docker-entrypoint

I am using podman to run a model on Azure. I need to run the model many times so i am sending these jobs to additional nodes that are managed by SLURM.

The podman command i use is:

```
podman run --rm --mount "type=bind,src=/inputfiles/,dst=/app/model" --mount "type=bind,src=/outputfiles,dst=/app/model/out" modelImage runscript.sh
```

This mounts local directories for input files and output files. The image is `modelImage` and `runscript.sh` is the script that is executed by the CMD command in my Dockerfile. The Dockerfile  just installs a linux distribution, libraries, model code, and compiles code

The last part of my Dockerfile reads

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
CMD ["runmodel.sh"]
```

So if i run the podman command above without the last argument, then `runmodel.sh` is executed, otherwise it is overridden with `runscript.sh`

This all works just fine, when i run my model on the main node (the controller) of my cluster.

However if i submit a job to an additional node then i get the following error:

> Error: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused
> "exec: "runscript.sh": executable file not found in $PATH": OCI
> runtime command not found error

I am not sure what this means exactly. Does it mean that /bin/bash can't be found in $PATH on the node? How should i be thinking about troubleshooting/resolving this?

It seems like the environment is different on new nodes than that of the controller.
Thanks

EDIT: Both `runscript.sh` and `runmodel.sh` are provided by the input bind mount. They do not exist in the image. The version of podman i am using is 1.6.4 (bundled with centos7). I am trying to get 4.5.0 installed to determine if this is the reason.

Comment: Do `runmodel.sh` and `runscript.sh` exist in the image? Or are they provided by one of the bind mounts?

Comment: @larsks. They are provided by one of the bind mounts. I'll add this to the thread